# melt multiindex pandas retain 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, stack, pivot, melt

df have:

```
 Index0       Workstream A    Workstream A
 Index 1        Section A        Section B
 Index 2      Start    End     Start   End
  ABC          2010   2011      2012   2013
```

df want:

```
Model Workstream Section Start End
ABC     A          A      2010 2011
ABC     A          B      2012 2013
```

Tried df.melt() but it is not unpivoting the multi index columns correctly

---

#### Setup

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
    ['Workstream A'], ['Section A', 'Section B'], ['Start', 'End']
], names=['Index 0', 'Index 1', 'Index 2'])

df = pd.DataFrame([['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013']], ['ABC'], midx)

with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print(df)

Index 0 Workstream A Workstream A Workstream A Workstream A
Index 1    Section A    Section A    Section B    Section B
Index 2        Start          End        Start          End
ABC             2010         2011         2012         2013
```

Comment: provide the code to reproduce this dataframe, since it's a multiindex and cant be reproduced by mere copying

Answer (score 1):

How about `stack`:

```
(df.stack(level=[0,1])
   .reset_index(level=[-1,-2])
)
```

Output (you could easily rename accordingly):

```
Index 2       Index 0    Index 1   End Start
ABC      Workstream A  Section A  2011  2010
ABC      Workstream A  Section B  2013  2012
```

---

#### With Renaming

```
def strip_col_name(c):
    """Strip out the column name from the values"""
    return c.str.replace(f'{c.name}\s*', '')

(
    df.stack([0, 1])
      .rename_axis(['Model', 'Workstream', 'Section'])
      .reset_index()
      .apply(strip_col_name)
)

Index 2 Model Workstream Section   End Start
0         ABC          A       A  2011  2010
1         ABC          A       B  2013  2012
```

Comment: Sorry for the intrusion (-:

Comment: @piRSquared haha, np. I was like *that function is certainly not my style*, and then I realized what happened. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the work involved manipulating the `MultiIndex` that forms your column headers.

If you have a choice, make your life easier by moving the fixed labels into the levels' names:

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
    ['A'], ['A', 'B'], ['Start', 'End']
], names=['Workstation', 'Section', None])
```

If you don't, manipulate them into the same idea:

```
midx = []
for level, name in enumerate(['Workstream', 'Section']):
    idx = df.columns.get_level_values(level) \
                .str.replace(name, '') \
                .str.strip() \
                .rename(name)
    midx.append(idx)

midx.append(df.columns.get_level_values(2).rename(None))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(midx)
```

After that, it only takes 2 lines of code to get the dataframe you want:

```
df.index.name = 'Model'
df.stack(level=[0,1]).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
  Model Workstream Section   End Start
0   ABC          A       A  2011  2010
1   ABC          A       B  2013  2012
```

Reorder the columns as needed.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Use [Quang Hoang's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58883554/2336654)

---

#### [`pandas.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

I'm disappointed that this is not as simple as I thought it was going to be.  To be fair, the starting dataframe isn't straight forward either.

I'd have liked to have used `pandas.wide_to_long` in a straight forward manner.  Eventually, I had to break this down and use `wide_to_long` in several iterations.

I don't recommend this!  I just wanted to go through the exercise.

---

```
kw        = dict(sep=' ', suffix='\\w+')      # I have to use a different suffix from the default
i0        = ['Model', 'Index 1', 'Index 2']   # I'm prepping lists for use in my function calls
i1        = ['Model', 'Index 2', 'Ws']

df_0      = df.rename_axis('Model')           # Rename the axis so that it has the appropriate name
stacked_0 = df_0.stack([1, 2]).reset_index() 

stacked_0

Index 0 Model    Index 1 Index 2 Workstream A
0         ABC  Section A     End         2011
1         ABC  Section A   Start         2010
2         ABC  Section B     End         2013
3         ABC  Section B   Start         2012
```

---

Time fo the first use of `wide_to_long`

```
df_1      = pd.wide_to_long(stacked_0, stubnames='Workstream', i=i0, j='Ws', **kw)

df_1

                           Workstream
Model Index 1   Index 2 Ws           
ABC   Section A End     A        2011
                Start   A        2010
      Section B End     A        2013
                Start   A        2012
```

---

```
stacked_1 = df_1['Workstream'].unstack('Index 1').reset_index()

stacked_1

Index 1 Model Index 2 Ws Section A Section B
0         ABC     End  A      2011      2013
1         ABC   Start  A      2010      2012
```

---

```
df_3      = pd.wide_to_long(stacked_1, stubnames='Section', i=i1, j='Sec', **kw)

df_3

                     Section
Model Index 2 Ws Sec        
ABC   End     A  A      2011
                 B      2013
      Start   A  A      2010
                 B      2012
```

---

```
df_3['Section'].unstack('Index 2').reset_index()

Index 2 Model Ws Sec   End Start
0         ABC  A   A  2011  2010
1         ABC  A   B  2013  2012
3
```

---

All together

```
kw        = dict(sep=' ', suffix='\\w+')
i0        = ['Model', 'Index 1', 'Index 2']
i1        = ['Model', 'Index 2', 'Ws']

df_0      = df.rename_axis('Model')
stacked_0 = df_0.stack([1, 2]).reset_index()

df_1      = pd.wide_to_long(stacked_0, stubnames='Workstream', i=i0, j='Ws', **kw)
stacked_1 = df_1['Workstream'].unstack('Index 1').reset_index()

df_3      = pd.wide_to_long(stacked_1, stubnames='Section', i=i1, j='Sec', **kw)
df_3['Section'].unstack('Index 2').reset_index()
```